# How to completely remove a mime association from my Linux system using the CLI tools?

Tags: mime-types

I'm running Arch Linux and KDE. I have installed Arch KDE on several devices and in the usual case there is no specific mime-type association for `.pub` files (which are public keys in my case). They will be opened by the default handler for plain text documents. This is what I expect to see on my standard Arch Linux install:

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype id_rsa_test.pub
text/plain
```

However, on my main desktop, `.pub` files are associated with ms-publisher.

```
$ xdg-mime query filetype id_rsa_test.pub
application/vnd.ms-publisher
```

I want to remove this association completely. Here are some of the places I found evidence of this association:

```
$ grep -irl '.pub' ./.local/share/mime/
./.local/share/mime/packages/application-vnd.ms-publisher.xml
./.local/share/mime/application/vnd.ms-publisher.xml
./.local/share/mime/globs
./.local/share/mime/globs2
./.local/share/mime/types
./.local/share/mime/mime.cache

$ sudo grep -irl 'ms-publisher' /usr
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.ms-publisher.xml
/usr/share/mime/globs
/usr/share/mime/globs2
/usr/share/mime/subclasses
/usr/share/mime/types
/usr/share/mime/mime.cache
/usr/share/icons/breeze/mimetypes/64/application-vnd.ms-publisher.svg
/usr/share/icons/breeze/mimetypes/22/application-vnd.ms-publisher.svg
/usr/share/icons/breeze/breeze-icons.rcc
/usr/share/icons/breeze/icon-theme.cache
/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/mimetypes/22/application-vnd.ms-publisher.svg
/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/breeze-icons-dark.rcc
/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/icon-theme.cache
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/xdg/draw.desktop
```

According to the `xdg-mime` man page, the `uninstall` command might do the trick. In my case at least, the `uninstall` command has no effect.

```
# xdg-mime uninstall /usr/share/mime/application/vnd.ms-publisher.xml
# echo $?
0

# sudo grep -irl 'ms-publisher' /usr
/usr/share/file/misc/magic.mgc
/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache
/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.ms-publisher.xml
/usr/share/mime/globs
/usr/share/mime/globs2
/usr/share/mime/subclasses
/usr/share/mime/types
/usr/share/mime/mime.cache
/usr/share/icons/breeze/mimetypes/64/application-vnd.ms-publisher.svg
/usr/share/icons/breeze/mimetypes/22/application-vnd.ms-publisher.svg
/usr/share/icons/breeze/breeze-icons.rcc
/usr/share/icons/breeze/icon-theme.cache
/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/mimetypes/22/application-vnd.ms-publisher.svg
/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/breeze-icons-dark.rcc
/usr/share/icons/breeze-dark/icon-theme.cache
/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/xdg/draw.desktop

# grep -irl '.pub' /usr/share/mime/
/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml
/usr/share/mime/packages/calibre-mimetypes.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/pkcs7-mime.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/pkcs8-encrypted.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/epub+zip.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/x-pkcs7-certificates.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/pkcs8.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/pkcs10.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/pkcs12.xml
/usr/share/mime/application/vnd.ms-publisher.xml
/usr/share/mime/globs
/usr/share/mime/globs2
/usr/share/mime/magic
/usr/share/mime/subclasses
/usr/share/mime/types
/usr/share/mime/generic-icons
/usr/share/mime/mime.cache
```

For my question, I want to know generally **how to remove *any* mime-type association from my system using only CLI tools.**

EDIT: response to answer:

On a new user account I show the following:

```
sudo pacman -Qs shared-mime-info
local/shared-mime-info 1.15-2
    Freedesktop.org Shared MIME Info

$ xdg-mime query filetype id_rsa_test.pub
text/plain

$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
atom.desktop

$ less ~/.config/mimeapps.list
/home/deleteme/.config/mimeapps.list: No such file or directory
```

This system has been updated multiple times (every day) and the ms-publisher association with `.pub` files has not come back. Note that this system has `shared-mime-info` installed and I am able to open public key files with a plain text editor, as I expect. In another user account on this system, I have my preferred association via an entry in `~/.config/mimeapps.list` for that user.

```
$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
org.kde.kate.desktop
```

Back to the main question: How do I completely remove the association of `.pub` files with Okular and/or Libre Office Draw at the system level? Even if that's not an approved method, how do I do it?

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565353/how-to-associate-a-new-custom-mime-type-with-files-based-on-file-extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .pub files will be opened by the default handler for plain text documents.
>   This is what I expect to see on my standard Arch Linux

There is **no** reason you should expect this. The `shared-mime-info` package assumes `.pub` is a Microsoft Publisher document. If you think the default should be `plain/text`, then you need to report this upstream.

I, myself, think it's a bug and they should not make a M$ proprietary format extension a priority over a GNU/linux native file extension. Or better still to use use **magic** in addition to **glob**

> I want to know generally how to remove any mime-type association from
>   my system using only CLI tools

You shouldn't remove system-wide mime-type associations at all. Even if you managed to do it, it would come back later with system updates.

What you should do is to add your own mime type that overwrites the system one. As you already know from your other question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/564816/how-to-install-a-new-custom-mime-type-on-my-linux-system-using-cli-tools), you can use **glob-deleteall** to overwrite the previous definitions

Comment: I updated the question. I appreciate this answer, and it does help, but I still want to know how to remove ms-publisher. It is not present on other Arch installs and they work fine. I want to get it off of my system, one way or the other.

Comment: On most of my Arch installs, things work like I expect without any user configuration (i.e., no entries in `~/.config/mimeapps.list`) . But on my main desktop `.pub` files have an unacceptable association. Most of all, I want to know how to remove that without using `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. I know it can be done because that's the situation I see on my other devices.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica: you said ms-publisher association is **not** present on other Arch installs but this is not true, **it's available** in all Arch's. To have different associations in different systems is normal even if you didn't customize it because it depends on the packages installed in each system and may be the order they are installed. You don't need to use `mimeapps.list` manually just right-click the app and associate it with your desired app

Comment: Right clicking to associate is just another way of using `~/.config/mimeapps.list`. I am seeing a certain behavior when the user has no `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and I want to understand how / why that is happening.

Comment: @MountainX-for-Monica: I already explained the **why** part. I am not sure what's your remaining issue.

Comment: I will ask it as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

there's an easier way.

I dunno about Dolphin, but in XFCE's Thunar, right click the file > **Open with** > **Set Default Applications**, Under **Recommended Applications**, right click an app name, choose **Forget Association**.

[image]

or easier still: just manually edit ~/.config/mimeapps.list and add app names under **[Removed Associations]**. This is actually what the above mentioned process does.

Answer (score 0):

System-wide default mime associations on your system are provided by `/usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`.

So, if you want your system to completely forget about your unpleasing mime type, you have to delete section `<mime-type type="application/vnd.ms-publisher">` ... `</mime-type>` from this file, and run `sudo update-mime-database /usr/share/mime` after that.

How to edit XML file "using the CLI tools" is another question:)

There is a problem clearly stated by Munzir Taha:

> it would come back later with system updates

And there is the ultimate solution - `i` (immutable) attribute: `sudo chattr +i /usr/share/mime/packages/freedesktop.org.xml`.

On Arch Linux, you will be warned by Pacman that the file can't be upgraded, but it doesn't break the whole upgrade process.